# Signature feature on web based Application on Android/iOS platforms

Tags: android, ios, signature

We are looking for technical feasibility for Signature feature on Web based Application on Android/iOS platforms. Our Business flow is to ask the Signature on Android/iOS based Mobile Phones or tablets.

Please let us know how to do it?

Regards
Apoorv Shah

Comment: What do you mean by signature?  Do you mean a cryptographic signature?  A signature like you'd make with pen and paper?  Something else?

Comment: We are looking for signature through Stylus pen on Mobile Phone or Tablet's screen for confirmation. This will be recorded for closing of the business.